# Ordering of Band Import into QGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am using QGIS 3.4,3

I want to use Raster Calculator to create NDVIs using Planetscope AnalyticMS_SR.tif

I know that the band order for Planetscope is BGRN
When I import the multiband SR into Raster calculator I see the bands numbered 1 to 4

When I look at the multiband SR in Layer Properties/Histogram the bands are numbered and colored indicating that B1 is R, B2 is G, B3 is B and B4 is purple and must be NIR. This is not the order of bands that Planetscope provides

When I look at the SR file in S-A CP Band Set I see a list of bands 1-4, but I cannot find other information about them because Planetscope is not included in the list for quick wavelength settings

How can I be sure that I have Red and NIR bands correctly identified in Raster Calculator to create the NDVI?

Comment: Can you please run `gdalinfo AnalyticMS_SR.tif | grep ^Band` and add the bands reported to your question? (Or run just `gdalinfo AnalyticMS_SR.tif`)

Comment: Ran Processor Toolbox - GDAL - Raster- Misc. - Raster info.

Comment: Your data is BGRN therefore B1 is blue, B2 is green etc in the raster calculator. QGIS is just showing you a default "RGB" composite using the first 3 bands in the wrong order - BGR. ArcGIS does this as well unless you change the default setting.

Comment: Thank you Luke for the clarification. Why is this not clearly stated in the documentation?